# Writing at a specific position in file

Tags: c++

What other options there are, other than `seekp`, to write at a specific position in an ascii file in c++?

Is there any way more performance efficient to do this, eg using `FILE` or in `boost`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/ ?

Comment: Just to be sure you realize, this will always overwrite what was at the given position, and there's no really simple way to make it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I found out this the hard way :/

Comment: Basically, what's the way to make it not work like i have pressed the insert key on my keyboard?